# How can I remove a mouse stuck in the air duct above a kitchen exhaust fan with built-in microwave?

Tags: kitchens, vent, ducts

Last night I heard noises in the cabinet above the microwave. There was nothing there but I heard squeaking and movement from the lower part of the metal air duct in the center of the cabinet.

[image: mouse noises from this space]

I am not sure how to approach removing the mouse from that space... This microwave was installed decades ago and I have no idea how to remove it.

So I am thinking that it may be possible to remove the lower part of the metal air duct?

Not even sure what these parts are called. Open to ideas.

Can't imagine the mouse being able to climb back to the roof and so I need to deal with this and soon.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: I am adding images for clarification:

The microwave and fan assembly seems to be held in place by two long screws in the front part of the wooden cabinet. I presume there's some kind of bracket in the back

[image: Screws in cabinet about microwave]

[image: Fan assembly above microwave]

Comment: It looks like that duct there is just taped in place, with some sort of tape - like gaffer tape, speed tape, insulation tape, etc, but I don't know, specialized for ducts or something.  It looks like nothing else really holds the duct in place, given how aggressively they have taped it.  (kinda looks like a hack job honestly).  Good luck finding that tape though, maybe try an HVAC specialty place.

Comment: Even after removing the tape and unscrewing the bottom part of the duct, we could not move the duct in any way. We ended up removing the microwave.

Comment: Make sure the squeaking sound isn't just the damper moving. Particularly on windy days, these can get sucked open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where there's a mouse there are mouse droppings and urine... I'd get that microwave out and clean it, if not replace it.

It looks like there are a pair of screws in the front corners of the cabinet going down into the microwave. If so.. those are probably what's holding up the front edge of the microwave. The rear edge is probably supported by some wall-mount bracket.

Don't forget to unplug the power cord. Then remove the two screws at the front and allow the unit to tip downward; after tipping it downward a bit you'll be able to lift the rear off of the wall bracket. It can sometimes be managed by one person, particularly if one knows how the assembly works.. but that not being the case here, recruit help to deal with the weight and any unanticipated fasteners/challenges.

Make sure both you and the assistant are comfortable with the idea of a spooked mouse dashing out of its prison, over you, and disappearing into the kitchen.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I'll try that. I added a couple more images.

Comment: Thank you. We were successful removing the microwave and found the dead mouse stuck in its fan. Will be replacing the microwave. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it would be easier to remove the cap from the roof vent and drop a heavy line for the mouse to use as a rope ladder than it would be to remove the assembly above your microwave oven.

Comment: I agree but I’m not sure the mouse is alive.